# Trying to get a "Name not found." for my while loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I am trying to make a conditional loop for my output by using a while loop. This is my output:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\junhao\doLandingPage.php on line 26
>   Name not found.

dbFunctions.php:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root'; //Change to your own one
$password = ''; //Change to your own one
$db = 'demo'; //Change to your own one

// Connect to the server
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

// Connect to the database
mysql_select_db('demo');
```

doLandingPage.php:

```
include 'dbFunctions.php';

$search = $_POST['search'];

// Query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE name = '$search'");
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>TITLE HERE.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

        <!-- Foundation -->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.js" media="screen">
    </head>    

    <body>

    <?php 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $id = $rows['id'];
            $name = $rows['name'];
            $table = $rows['table'];

            echo "<h1>$name</h1>"
            echo "<h2>$table</h2>"
        }
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Name not found.";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the query first. You are trying to use `mysqli_num_rows()` on a regular string.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed mysql and mysqli since both are different please notice mysql is deprecated use mysqli.

try this code :-

```
<?php 

         if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $table = $row['table'];

                    echo "<h1>$name</h1>"
                    echo "<h2>$table</h2>"

                }
          }else{
                echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Name not found.';
          }

    ?>
```